# Three.js - Object lookAt() 90 degrees perpendicular from path it's travelling on

Tags: javascript, three.js

The idea is to have a square room in which an object (and the camera a little further back to be able to view the object - i.e. over the shoulder camera) moves around from corner to corner, facing the walls at all times but curving smoothly round, so that when transitioning from one wall to the other, the object (and camera) are not exactly 90 degrees perpendicular, but transition from 90 degrees perpendicular with one wall, to 90 degrees perpendicular with the next.

**How I went about it**

My solution to this was to create a `CatmullRomCurve3` from an array of 4 sets of coordinates (4 corners) and then have the object and camera animate along this curve. I have got this to work successfully with the code below, but my problem is that the object and camera are both looking at (`lookAt`) the path in front of them. I like that the angle of the object and camera constantly change to match the angle of the path, and I basically want to offset this by 90 degrees (I think?), so that they still move in the same way, but `lookAt` the wall.

**So basically, what I want:**

- Object and camera moving along the path in the same way, but offset their `rotation`/`lookAt` so that they are always facing a wall/corner and not in front of them.
- Right now I understand how to offset the camera slightly behind the object to give an over shoulder perspective, but I imagine this would change with the object facing the walls as the camera then needs to be behind the object on a different axis, so an explanation for this would be great too.

**My Code to create the curve**

```
var curve;
function createCurvePath() {

//Array of points
var points = [
    [-80, 5, 35],
    [-80, 5, 192.5],
    [80, 5, 192.5],
    [80, 5, 35]
];

//Convert the array of points into vertices
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var x = points[i][0];
    var y = points[i][1];
    var z = points[i][2];
    points[i] = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
}


//Create a closed curve
curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);

curve.closed = true;

var points = curve.getPoints( 200 );
var geomCurvePath = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

var matCurvePath = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
var CurvePath = new THREE.Line( geomCurvePath, matCurvePath );



scene.add(CurvePath);
}
```

**Code to animate (render loop)**

```
// loop that runs every frame to render scene and camera
function render(){
requestAnimationFrame(render);

// Move camera along path
percentage += 0.0005;
var p1 = curve.getPointAt(percentage % 1);
var p2 = curve.getPointAt((percentage + 0.01) % 1);
camera.position.set(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
object.position.set(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
camera.lookAt(p2);
object.lookAt(p2);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an option, use `.applyAxisAngle()` method:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 100, 300);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 100);
controls.update();

var points = [
  new THREE.Vector3(-80, 5, 35),
  new THREE.Vector3(-80, 5, 192.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(80, 5, 192.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(80, 5, 35)
];

var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
curve.closed = true;

var curvePoints = curve.getPoints(200);
var geomCurvePath = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curvePoints);
var matCurvePath = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
});
var CurvePath = new THREE.Line(geomCurvePath, matCurvePath);
scene.add(CurvePath);

var pointerGeom = new THREE.ConeGeometry(4, 20, 4);
pointerGeom.translate(0, 10, 0);
pointerGeom.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);
var pointer = new THREE.Mesh(pointerGeom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(pointer);

var p1 = new THREE.Vector3();
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3();
var lookAt = new THREE.Vector3();
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var percentage = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  percentage += 0.0005;
  curve.getPointAt(percentage % 1, p1);
  curve.getPointAt((percentage + 0.001) % 1, p2);
  lookAt.copy(p2).sub(p1).applyAxisAngle(axis, -Math.PI * 0.5).add(p1); // look at the point 90 deg from the path
  pointer.position.copy(p1);
  pointer.lookAt(lookAt);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: any idea how I would have the camera do the exact same thing but be offset from the object and a little higher up, so following the exact same path of the object and angled the exact same way but just offset further from the "walls" or offset from the actual path as another way to explain it

Comment: @JJGerrish Add the camera as a child to the moving object.