# Three.js - Rotate camera separately from it's parent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene in which an Object moves around a `CatmullRomCurve3` path, going left when you press the `left` or `down` arrow keys and right when you press the `right` or `up` arrow keys.

I initially [had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019038/three-js-object-lookat-90-degrees-perpendicular-from-path-its-travelling-on) in which I wanted the Object to face 90 degrees from the path instead of facing along the path. You can find my code for this scene there. This problem was solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022274/9267033).

Basically, all I had to do was implement the following code to rotate the object:

```
object.lookAt((p2).sub(p1).applyAxisAngle(axis, -Math.PI * 0.5).add(p1));
```

Although the object now rotated correctly, I now had the problem that the `camera` wasn't facing the same direction as the object or moving with the object (I wanted an over the shoulder type perspective of the object) but someone suggested I fix this by just adding the camera as a child of the object, *which worked!*

**The New Problem**

I now want the object's default position to be facing 90 degrees away from the path (as it is), but when you press the `left` or `down` arrows, I want the object to face left (back along the path as it was originally), and face the other way when the `right` and `up` arrows are pressed.

I managed to get this to work by setting up some `if` statements in the `render` loop that change the value of `-Math.PI * 0.5` to either `-Math.PI * 2` or `-Math.PI * 0.5` for left and right depending on which key is pressed.

However, this also causes the camera to take that new `lookAt` value as it is a child of the object, but I want the camera to always stay in the same position (i.e. facing 90 degrees from the path, as the object does when it is still).

**So, how can I stop the camera from rotating/moving/changing it's `lookAt` (I'm not sure which one it is) when the Object changes?**

It seems like nothing I do to the camera affects it, it is always locked to the same orientation of the object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `THREE.Group()`, add your object and camera to it. Whilst that group is looking 90 degrees from the path, you can free to rotate the object as you wish, and the camera stays still.

Comment: @prisoner849 almost works but now `object.lookAt((p2).sub(p1).applyAxisAngle(axis, -Math.PI * 2).add(p1));` rotates weirdly (seems to be rotating/looking at on all axis and not just on y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question correctly:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 20, -20);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(300, 30);
grid.position.setZ(100);
scene.add(grid);

var points = [
  new THREE.Vector3(-80, 5, 35),
  new THREE.Vector3(-80, 5, 192.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(80, 5, 192.5),
  new THREE.Vector3(80, 5, 35)
];

var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
curve.closed = true;

var curvePoints = curve.getPoints(200);
var geomCurvePath = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curvePoints);
var matCurvePath = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
});
var CurvePath = new THREE.Line(geomCurvePath, matCurvePath);
scene.add(CurvePath);

var group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(group);

group.add(camera);

var pointerGeom = new THREE.ConeGeometry(4, 20, 4);
pointerGeom.translate(0, 10, 0);
pointerGeom.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);
var pointer = new THREE.Mesh(pointerGeom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
group.add(pointer);

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  turn(Math.PI * 0.5)
});
btnRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  turn(-Math.PI * 0.5)
});

function turn(angle) {
  pointer.rotation.y += angle;
}

var p1 = new THREE.Vector3();
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3();
var lookAt = new THREE.Vector3();
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var percentage = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  percentage += 0.0005;
  curve.getPointAt(percentage % 1, p1);
  curve.getPointAt((percentage + 0.001) % 1, p2);
  lookAt.copy(p2).sub(p1).applyAxisAngle(axis, -Math.PI * 0.5).add(p1); // look at the point 90 deg from the path
  group.position.copy(p1);
  group.lookAt(lookAt);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="btnLeft">left</button>
  <button id="btnRight">right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't directly solve it but you made me realise that the reason it wasn't working was because I was trying to change the object's `lookAt()` when all I had to do was rotate it normally with Math.PI as it was not following the path but it's parent group was! Thanks so much again haha